# Automation failing when running Apple script

Tags: applescript, action, automator, quicktime, appleevents

Hello I am using this Apple script in Automator to auto launch and play in full screens video using quick time.

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set theMovie to open file "Users:ronaldwise:Movies:Jarvis Startup.mp4"
    tell theMovie
        set the presenting to true
        set the looping to false
        play
    end tell
end tell
```

The Script runs just fine when I press play in automator however, when I try and start the automation application outside of automator I receive this Message.

"The action "Run AppleScript" encountered an error "Not authorized to send Apple Events to QuickTime Player"

My Automation workflow looks like this

[Workflow screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOmUN.jpg)

I have allowed access to Security privacy > Accessability to the following apps: Terminal, Consul, AEServer, Automator, Consul, and Quicktime player.

I have allowed access to Security Privacy>Full Disk Access to the same above listed programs.

I have allowed access to Security Privacy > Automation to the following: Automator>QuickTime Player and Terminal>Finder

I am at a loss any help please.

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: Putting aside the OS version for a moment, if you're saving the workflow as an application, it's probably that application which needs special access (and probably not all those listed).

Comment: I have given the application permission as well. To both the accessibility and disk access. I am running ios11.0

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with Accessibility and Full Disk Access

You have to add the key [NSAppleEventsUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsappleeventsusagedescription) in Info.plist of the script application.

Open the application package in Finder with `Right-click > Show Package Contents`, then open the `Info.plist` file in `Contents` with a text editor and insert

```
<key>NSAppleEventsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Jarvis needs to control QuickTime Player</string>
```

The position of the key value pair is irrelevant but it must not follow directly a `key` line.

Comment: But how do you do that. I ave been trying to figure out how to make that work for hours. I am not familiar with this kind of thing and have never programmed any type of automation or written any code. Honestly I’m surprised I figured out this much. What does that process look like?

Comment: So I added the suggested key which prompted me to allow the access. Now in security and privacy QuickTime player is listed below Terminal. However when the application launches at login I still receive the same error. “The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “Not authorized to send Apple Events to QuickTime Player”